# Does an iPhone broadcast it's MAC address when searching for Wi-Fi Access Points?

Tags: ios, wifi

I have just read an article saying that a company named `Euclid analytics,` can report if an iPhone is nearby by seeing it's MAC address being broadcast over Wi-Fi.

How can analytics systems see the iPhone's MAC adress without pairing with it in anyway before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a device looks for Wi-Fi access points, it sends the MAC address as part of the Probe Request. You can disable Wi-Fi to prevent this. iOS 8 adds [MAC address randomization support](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147613/does-ios-8s-mac-address-randomization-give-the-actual-mac-address-once-connecte) to improve user privacy.

Comment: This assumption is strange, because you send your mac only to a network whom you connected to. I dont think any access point out there advertising its network name, can get mac adress of any device that see her?? Am i wrong?

Comment: There is a passive mode, listening for Beacon Frames, as well as an active Probe Request. See networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/17225. An AP can obtain the MAC address from the probe requests.